# TPIL 3.6: example : ¬(p ↔ ¬p)

Tags: lean

[Section 3.6](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/propositions_and_proofs.html#examples-of-propositional-validities) of Theorem Proving in Lean shows the following:

```
example : ¬(p ↔ ¬p) := sorry
```

Let's start with the original type:

```
¬(p ↔ ¬p)
```

Rewrite the outer `¬` in terms of `→`:

```
(p ↔ ¬p) → false
```

Then the inner `¬`:

```
(p ↔ (p → false)) → false
```

OK, let's use that. I'm assuming that the proof will initially contain an `assume` to accept the `(p ↔ (p → false))`:

```
example : (p ↔ (p → false)) → false :=

    (assume hppf : (p ↔ (p → false)),

        <rest of proof here>)
```

I can use `iff.elim_left` and `iff.elim_right` to pull out parts of `hppf`:

```
example : (p ↔ (p → false)) → false :=

    (assume hppf : (p ↔ (p → false)),

        have hppf1 : p → (p → false), from iff.elim_left hppf,
        have hppf2 : (p → false) → p, from iff.elim_right hppf,

    )
```

But not sure if that's the right approach. Sure, I have `hppf1` now, but there doesn't seem to be a `p` to apply it to. Similar for `hppf2`.

Should `iff.intro` somehow be used?

These previous questions:

- [example : ((p ∨ q) → r) → (p → r) ∧ (q → r)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58464712/268581)
- [example: (p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r) → p ∨ (q ∧ r)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58406492/268581)

involved `↔` expressions at the top level. In those cases, I explored the left-to-right and right-to-left cases separately.

However, in this example, the `↔` is "inside" a `¬` so I'm not sure that that approach works here.

Any suggestions welcome!

---

**UPDATE**

Here's an approach that appears to work:

```
example : (p ↔ (p → false)) → false :=

    (assume hppf : (p ↔ (p → false)),

        have hppf1 : p → (p → false), from iff.elim_left hppf,
        have hppf2 : (p → false) → p, from iff.elim_right hppf,

        have hpf : (p → false), from (assume hp : p, ((hppf1 hp) hp)),

        have hp : p, from (hppf2 hpf),

        (hppf1 hp) hp)
```

Thanks to the folks at the Lean zulip chatroom for their help on this one! 
([Link to the thread](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/113489-new-members/topic/example.20.3A.20.C2.AC(p.20.E2.86.94.20.C2.ACp)) on there where we discussed this.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an interactive way of playing with these puzzles:
https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#code=example%20%28p%20%3A%20Prop%29%20%3A%20%C2%AC%28p%20%E2%86%94%20%C2%ACp%29%20%3A%3D%0Abegin%0A%20%20assume%20H%2C%0A%20%20have%20hp%20%3A%20p%20%3A%3D%20H.mpr%20%28%CE%BB%20hp%2C%20_%29%2C%0A%20%20all_goals%0A%20%20%7B%20have%20hp_copy%20%3A%3D%20hp%2C%0A%20%20%20%20rw%20H%20at%20hp_copy%2C%0A%20%20%20%20contradiction%20%7D%2C%0Aend

```
example (p : Prop) : ¬(p ↔ ¬p) :=
begin
  assume H,
  have hp : p := H.mpr (λ hp, _),
  all_goals
  { have hp_copy := hp,
    rw H at hp_copy,
    contradiction },
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way without making appear "false" in Lean 4. Use `.mp` to get proof in the forward direction and use `.mpr` to get proof in the backward direction.

```
example : ¬(p ↔ ¬p) := 
  (fun h: p ↔ ¬p => 
    have hnpf : ¬p := 
      (fun hp: p => 
        absurd hp (h.mp hp))
    have hpf : p := (h.mpr hnpf)
    absurd hpf hnpf)
```